# Create an (n,1) array from int values in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, integer

I simply want to create an (n,1) array from the int values (dist) in my for a loop.
For now, I only have a succession of int values, since I'm printing the "dist" value in each iteration.
How do I incorporate each dist into an array (in this case only an n-vector), so that array[i][0] is the dist value from the ith iteration of the for loop?

I know it must be really simple, I'm only starting out on NumPy. I've tried out with insert, append, doesn't seem to work. My distmatrix initialized in the beginning is not used...

here is the code for now:

```
distmat=np.zeros((len(CoordNodesRad[:,0]),1),int)
lat = CoordNodesRad[:,0]
lng = CoordNodesRad[:,1]
for i in range(len(CoordNodesRad[:,0])):
        dist = distanceGPS(depot[0], depot[1], lat[i], lng[i])
        #print(int(dist))
        #distmat=np.append(distmat,dist,axis=0)
        print(dist)
        distmat=np.insert(dist,i,dist)
print(distmat)
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. We have no idea what `CoordNodesRad` is OR what `distanceGPS()` function does, what its input output looks like.

Comment: It's easier and faster to append values to a list.

Comment: CoordNodesRad is an array of n lines, 2 columns with the latitude and longitude of n points. distanceGPS() calculates the distance from a depot (with known GPS coordinates) to all these other n nodes. They are not relevant (I think) because they work, I have the actual results (i.e. the distances from the depot to the n nodes) in the printed "dist" values, but I want them stored in an array (in my case "distmat").

Answer (score -1):

Eventually I used a simple list, and append my "dist" values to it.
If someone has something quicker than passing by the list, then creating the array...
here is my new code (the commented lines don't matter)

```
disttodepot=[]
lat = CoordNodesRad[:,0]
lng = CoordNodesRad[:,1]
for i in range(len(CoordNodesRad[:,0])):
#    for j in CoordNodesRad:
#   dist = np.append(dist, [[i, j]], axis=0)
        dist = distanceGPS(depot[0], depot[1], lat[i], lng[i])
        #print(int(dist))
        #distmat=np.append(distmat,dist,axis=0)
        #print(dist)
        disttodepot.append(int(dist))
print(disttodepot)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).